# Override product description

Tags: magento2, overrides, template-override, product-description

I need to add some things to the Magento 2 description. I can't do it via admin area since the data needs to be generated procedurally, so I tried an override, but the closest I've got is this

[image]

I need my description to appear in the Magento description tab, not to create a new tab. Can someone help me with this?

The code I'm trying is the following one:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" template="Module::product/view/details.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Descripción</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what code or thing you try to achieve this one?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I'm trying to achieve it on all products. What I want to do is show in the description all the possible options the product has. I have edited the question to add the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom phtml file in the module or design **templates** directory.

Create or modify **catalog_product_view.xml** in your module or design **layout** directory.
Add following code in xml in **body** tag.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::custom.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Flush cache.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!